# Create VirtualHost with @Configuration class

Tags: spring-amqp

I can create Exchanges,Queues/bindings with @Configuration & @Bean cleanly (as below) but I did not find a way to create VirtualHost in similar way. I just want to use default 'guest' user for this virtual host. Is there a way? I have 1 producer and 3 listeners running in separate apps. I thought it would be easy to have a class with this configuration and copy it to all these apps. I think this is a very common requirement. What is the best way to create required config in this scenario?

```
@Configuration
public class amqpConfiguration {
@Autowired
RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

@Bean
TopicExchange testExchange() {
    return new TopicExchange("test.exchange");
}

TopicExchange errorExchange() {
    return new TopicExchange("error.change");
}

@Bean
Queue erorQueue() {
    return new Queue("error.q", true);
}

@Bean
Binding errorQueueBinding(Queue erorQueue, TopicExchange errorExchange) {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(erorQueue).to(errorExchange).with("error.q");
}

@Bean
Queue testQueue() {
    Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    args.put("x-dead-letter-exchange", "test.exchange");
    args.put("x-dead-letter-routing-key", "error.q");
    return new Queue("test.q", true, false, false, args);
}

@Bean
Binding inQueueBinding(Queue testQueue, TopicExchange testExchange) {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(testQueue).to(testExchange).with("test.q");
}
```

}

Comment: Found another [post](http://rabbitmq.1065348.n5.nabble.com/Configure-Queue-under-specific-vhost-in-Spring-Project-td35374.html). This suggest that I can specify vhost in connectionfactory but does not look like I can create a new virtualhost.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can do that only from the Broker perspective, or using [Management Plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html) HTTP API:

> /api/vhosts/name -    An individual virtual host. As a virtual host usually only has a name, you do not need an HTTP body when PUTing one of these.

Well, from big height yes, you can do that: using Spring `RestTemplate` to perform that REST API to create a desired `vhost`.